# Keep calculations are individual level material when unfiltered to show all materials

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a problem. At the individual material level, the variances calculate correctly to measure the difference in the components consumed by each individual material.

However, when I unfilter to display all materials, the calculation shows the undesired calculations now computed at an aggregated level.

How would I display a summary of all correct individual calculations?

I want to see not $136.01 for 30210 at the total level but $17,856.14.

```
Dairy test = 
CALCULATE(sumx(values(mm60[Material]),[component net value]*[YOY Component Diff]))
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: What exactly are you filtering on? Does the calculation need to return the same value for each material ignoring the component?

Comment: Assuming the question above, the DAX would look like this:
`Dairy test = 
CALCULATE(SUM(mm60[YOY Component Diff])*SUM(mm60[component net value]), ALL(mm60[Component Description]))`
If YOY Component Diff and component net value are already measures, you can remove the SUM.